# Sending Email in asp.net mvc use webmail class to the email address from textboxt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, textbox, webmail

I want to send email to dynamic email address that input from the text box in the form.
what code should I write in web mail .send() that come from textbox In ASP.NET MVC?
I want to email anybody who write email in textbox.

[HttpGet]

```
    public ViewResult RsvForm()
    {


        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
 public ViewResult RsvForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
}
else
{
    return View();
}
```

}

```
public class GuestResponse
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your email address")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify whether you'll attend")]
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
          @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <p>Your name:@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)</p>
        <p>Your email:@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Email)</p>
        <p>Your Phone:@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
        <p>
        Will you attend?
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.WillAttend,new[]{
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Yes,I'll be there",Value=bool.TrueString},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="No,I can't",Value=bool.FalseString}},"Choose an option")
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
      }   

     try
    {
    WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.MyHost.com";
    WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
    WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
    WebMail.UserName = "info@Mysite.com";
    WebMail.Password = "GF@gzKPkD";
    WebMail.From = "Info@Mysite.com";
    WebMail.Send("Email Address Should come from textbox who user input", "RSVP Notification", Model.Name + "is" + ((Model.WillAttend ?? false) ? "" : "not") + "attending");

    }
    catch (Exception)
     {
            @:<b>Sorry-we couldn't send the email to confirm your RSVP.</b>
            }
```

Comment: Just a note! Better to remove all sensitive data from your questions before posting them to SO

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an `Action` where you will send all your form data. And than in your `Action` you need to use appropriate properties of `Model` passed in to build your email you going to send.

Is you very new to ASP.NET MVC please [read that before](http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/)

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public class EmailModel
{
public string Name { get; set; } 
public string Email { get; set; } 
public string Phone { get; set; }
public bool WillAttend { get; set; } 
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form"   }))
{
<fieldset>
 @Html.ValidationSummary();
<p>Your name:@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)</p>
<p>Your email:@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Email)</p>
<p>Your Phone:@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
<p>
Will you attend?
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.WillAttend,new[]{
new SelectListItem(){Text="Yes,I'll be there",Value=bool.TrueString},
new SelectListItem(){Text="No,I can't",Value=bool.FalseString}},"Choose an option")
</p>   
<input class="form-button" data-type="submit" type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
```

}

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(EmailModel emailModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    if(emailModel.WillAttend)
    {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();           

            mail.From = emailModel.Email.ToString();
            mail.To.Add("emailaddress");
            mail.Subject = "Test enquiry from "+ emailModel.Name;
            mail.Body = emailModel.Message.ToString();

            smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I want to send from my email to email that input anybody in the textbox.